# ssh is no longer working from the commandline

Tags: ssh

I was trying to stop ssh from terminating after 10 minutes.

I followed an instruction [here](https://serverfault.com/a/822735/211898) saying to modify a config file and restart the service with:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
```

Now `ssh pi@12.34.567.89` just hangs.

I've reverted the config file and rebooted the machine but it still hangs.

How to fix?

PS `sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd` + another reboot also fails.

```
[pi@pis-iMac] ~ 
> launchctl list | grep ssh
-   0   com.openssh.ssh-agent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to load the service again.

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Comment: Still no luck, `ps aux | grep ssh` isn't reporting anything either. Do I need another reboot?

Comment: @Pi Hmm, I've not had to reboot when using ‘load -w’ with other services, but you can try. If it doesn't work at all, my guess is that the change to the config file has broken ssh and it can't parse the file properly or something, but that's only a guess and I don't have enough knowledge of ssh specifically.